# If every point of $S$ is a limit point of $S$ and $S$ is closed, then we say that $S$ is.....?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I have a set $S \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that

$x \in S \implies x$ is a limit point of $S$

and

$S$ is closed

Can I conclude that $S$ is connected?

Comment: A perfect space/set.

Comment: @amWhy Sure. It wasn't clear to me whether S was a topological space in its own right or a subset of some ambient space. Though, if the latter, then we can't say that S is dense in S either; S might have (S-)isolated points that are not isolated in the bigger space.

Comment: Edit: $S$ is a a countably infinite collection of points in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Edit: $S$ is closed as well.

Comment: So $S$ is a countable infinite collection as you state in the comments here or just any set as you say in the edit above? If it's any set in which all points are limit points and is closed, it's definitely not the case that it's necessarily connected. For example, take any two closed disks that do not overlap.

Comment: You seem to be changing the question a lot. What do you actually want to ask?

Comment: @Billy Sorry for the changes. I'm looking at a particular set and just discovered that it was closed so I was hoping to simply give you guys more information about $S$. 

Probably should have waited a bit longer before posting the question. 

The question is now precisely what I am asking.

Comment: Then your set is a perfect set. But not necessarily connected.

Comment: The two point set $A=\{(1,0), (-1,0)\}$ is closed and both points of $A$ are limit points of $A$ but it is not connected. Never mind, I didn't catch the edit for countably infinite. Take $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb C$. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

> your set is a perfect set. But not necessarily connected.

– amWhy Apr 23 at 4:27

For example, the union of two disjoint closed intervals has the properties in your question, but is not connected.

Connectedness stands apart from the properties such as bounded, closed, open, compact, having no isolated points... you will not get connectedness from any combination of those.